# FORMSOF term not search the key words of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In my column I have and word but When I try to search `'and'` into `FormOF` it will not search.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    AttributeID, attribute_key, display_name, Segmentmaster.segmentname as SegmentName 
FROM 
    AttributeMaster 
LEFT JOIN
    Segmentmaster ON Segmentmaster.segmentID = AttributeMaster.segmentId 
WHERE
    CONTAINS(attribute_key, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, "and")' ) 
    OR CONTAINS(display_name, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, "and")' )  
ORDER BY  
    AttributeID ASC
```

Is it `FormsOf` not search the keywords of SQL Server and special character like `&,_,of ...`

Please guide me..

Comment: If I put any key words in FORM OF then it's not working

Comment: Suppose this is my column value 'Association and Club' and now I want to search 'and' but it's will not work. If I search whole word 'Association and Club' then it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `'and'` is in [STOPLIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx). You need check this

```
SELECT stopword
FROM sys.fulltext_indexes i JOIN sys.fulltext_stoplists l ON i.stoplist_id = l.stoplist_id 
                            JOIN sys.fulltext_stopwords w ON l.stoplist_id = w.stoplist_id
WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('AttributeMaster') AND stopword LIKE 'and'
```

_test and sony's words Full Text find with no problem, but unfortunately for &, _ character symbols it not work.Possible can try use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AttributeID, attribute_key, 
                display_name, Segmentmaster.segmentname as SegmentName 
FROM AttributeMaster LEFT JOIN Segmentmaster ON Segmentmaster.segmentID = AttributeMaster.segmentId 
WHERE CONTAINS(attribute_key, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, "_test")' ) 
  OR CONTAINS(display_name, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, "_test")' )
  OR attribute_key LIKE '&'
  OR display_name LIKE '&'
ORDER BY AttributeID ASC
```

Comment: StopList concept helpful me to search the keywords like and,or,of into my fulltext search. Thank you for that. This query not helpful. Can u help me how to find &,_.' special character into fulltext search.

Comment: Only this &,_.' special character?

Comment: yes I just want to search character like _test, & ,  sony's time words